# gdalwarp - ERROR 2: gdalwarpoperation.cpp, 2401: cannot allocate 839889004 bytes on QGIS 3.16

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, gdalwarp

I have two Int16 DEMs of 129600x64800 cells that cover the entire globe. The projection is WGS84 [EPSG:4326]. One contains only the elevation above sea level (no data cells above oceans), and the other also has the bathymetry of oceans (thus there are no "no data" cells). They both have the same file size (~16GB) and there is no compression method applied.
I use `Warp` to reproject the raster in a custom projection based on the Loximuthal projection (+proj=loxim).

When I use Warp on the first DEM (no bathymetry) no issue occurs, when I use Warp on the latter, sometimes it returns this error: ERROR 2: gdalwarpoperation.cpp, 2401: cannot allocate 839889004 bytes.

This is the log of a couple of operations using only different target resolutions:

```
Caricamento layer

Algoritmo in esecuzione 2/4…
In avvio l'algoritmo Riproiezione…
Parametri in ingresso:
{'DATA_TYPE': 0,
'EXTRA': '--config GDAL_CACHEMAX 512',
'INPUT': 'MERIT_GEBCO_10arcsec_Int_33556080_8f79_46a3_b90f_77fbe4ac717d',
'MULTITHREADING': False,
'NODATA': None,
'OPTIONS': '',
'OUTPUT': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':C:/DATA/Cartografia/Digital Elevation Models/Loxim Proj/DEM/DEM_9103164_0.tif, 'createOptions': {}}>,
'RESAMPLING': 0,
'SOURCE_CRS': <QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem: EPSG:4326>,
'TARGET_CRS': <QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem: USER:100003>,
'TARGET_EXTENT': None,
'TARGET_EXTENT_CRS': None,
'TARGET_RESOLUTION': 9103164.0}

GDAL command:
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs "PROJCRS[\"unknown\",BASEGEOGCRS[\"unknown\",DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],ID[\"EPSG\",6326]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],ID[\"EPSG\",8901]]],CONVERSION[\"unknown\",METHOD[\"Loximuthal\"],PARAMETER[\"Latitude of natural origin\",0,ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],ID[\"EPSG\",8801]],PARAMETER[\"Longitude of natural origin\",0,ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],ID[\"EPSG\",8802]],PARAMETER[\"False easting\",0,LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],PARAMETER[\"False northing\",0,LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],ID[\"EPSG\",8807]]],CS[Cartesian,2],AXIS[\"(E)\",east,ORDER[1],LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1,ID[\"EPSG\",9001]]],AXIS[\"(N)\",north,ORDER[2],LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1,ID[\"EPSG\",9001]]]]" -tr 9103164.0 9103164.0 -r near -of GTiff --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 512 "C:/DATA/Cartografia/Digital Elevation Models/MERIT DEM/MERIT_GEBCO_10arcsec_Int.tif" "C:/DATA/Cartografia/Digital Elevation Models/Loxim Proj/DEM/DEM_9103164_0.tif"
GDAL command output:
Creating output file that is 4P x 2L.

Processing C:/DATA/Cartografia/Digital Elevation Models/MERIT DEM/MERIT_GEBCO_10arcsec_Int.tif [1/1] : 0Using internal nodata values (e.g. -3.40282e+38) for image C:/DATA/Cartografia/Digital Elevation Models/MERIT DEM/MERIT_GEBCO_10arcsec_Int.tif.

Copying nodata values from source C:/DATA/Cartografia/Digital Elevation Models/MERIT DEM/MERIT_GEBCO_10arcsec_Int.tif to destination C:/DATA/Cartografia/Digital Elevation Models/Loxim Proj/DEM/DEM_9103164_0.tif.

...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

Algoritmo Riproiezione eseguito correttamente...
Execution completed in 1631.12 seconds
Risultati:
{'OUTPUT': 'C:/DATA/Cartografia/Digital Elevation Models/Loxim '
'Proj/DEM/DEM_9103164_0.tif'}

Caricamento layer

Algoritmo in esecuzione 3/4…
In avvio l'algoritmo Riproiezione…
Parametri in ingresso:
{'DATA_TYPE': 0,
'EXTRA': '--config GDAL_CACHEMAX 512',
'INPUT': 'MERIT_GEBCO_10arcsec_Int_33556080_8f79_46a3_b90f_77fbe4ac717d',
'MULTITHREADING': False,
'NODATA': None,
'OPTIONS': '',
'OUTPUT': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':C:/DATA/Cartografia/Digital Elevation Models/Loxim Proj/DEM/DEM_9093340_0.tif, 'createOptions': {}}>,
'RESAMPLING': 0,
'SOURCE_CRS': <QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem: EPSG:4326>,
'TARGET_CRS': <QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem: USER:100003>,
'TARGET_EXTENT': None,
'TARGET_EXTENT_CRS': None,
'TARGET_RESOLUTION': 9093340.0}

GDAL command:
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs "PROJCRS[\"unknown\",BASEGEOGCRS[\"unknown\",DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],ID[\"EPSG\",6326]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],ID[\"EPSG\",8901]]],CONVERSION[\"unknown\",METHOD[\"Loximuthal\"],PARAMETER[\"Latitude of natural origin\",0,ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],ID[\"EPSG\",8801]],PARAMETER[\"Longitude of natural origin\",0,ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],ID[\"EPSG\",8802]],PARAMETER[\"False easting\",0,LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],PARAMETER[\"False northing\",0,LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],ID[\"EPSG\",8807]]],CS[Cartesian,2],AXIS[\"(E)\",east,ORDER[1],LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1,ID[\"EPSG\",9001]]],AXIS[\"(N)\",north,ORDER[2],LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1,ID[\"EPSG\",9001]]]]" -tr 9093340.0 9093340.0 -r near -of GTiff --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 512 "C:/DATA/Cartografia/Digital Elevation Models/MERIT DEM/MERIT_GEBCO_10arcsec_Int.tif" "C:/DATA/Cartografia/Digital Elevation Models/Loxim Proj/DEM/DEM_9093340_0.tif"
GDAL command output:
Creating output file that is 4P x 2L.

Processing C:/DATA/Cartografia/Digital Elevation Models/MERIT DEM/MERIT_GEBCO_10arcsec_Int.tif [1/1] : 0Using internal nodata values (e.g. -3.40282e+38) for image C:/DATA/Cartografia/Digital Elevation Models/MERIT DEM/MERIT_GEBCO_10arcsec_Int.tif.

Copying nodata values from source C:/DATA/Cartografia/Digital Elevation Models/MERIT DEM/MERIT_GEBCO_10arcsec_Int.tif to destination C:/DATA/Cartografia/Digital Elevation Models/Loxim Proj/DEM/DEM_9093340_0.tif.

...10...20...30...40...50ERROR 2: gdalwarpoperation.cpp, 2401: cannot allocate 839889004 bytes

Algoritmo Riproiezione eseguito correttamente...
Execution completed in 1094.65 seconds
Risultati:
{'OUTPUT': 'C:/DATA/Cartografia/Digital Elevation Models/Loxim '
'Proj/DEM/DEM_9093340_0.tif'}
```

The only thing I've noticed is that this error occurs mainly with high target resolutions (and thus a small output size). Still, I can't understand why it worked with a resolution of 9103164 meters and not with a resolution of 9093340 meters (which is smaller). Does anyone know something more about this issue?

Comment: Is this a real use case? You are pushing 129600x64800 cells from the source file into a new tiff that has only 8 pixels?

Comment: @user30184 That's a fair question. For a personal project, I started working warping this DEM with the maximum target resolution possible of 40075017 meters (equal to the length of the equator) with an output of 1x1 cells. If it is true that with a low target resolution this issue doesn't occur, I can work with a smaller input DEM and edit manually small output up to, let's say, 100 cells. Above that, it would be troublesome.
I was trying then to figure out what could trigger this error.

Comment: Low resolution means big pixels, high resolution means small pixels. If you need extremely low resolution maybe you should create a downsampled version of the input with `gdal_translate -tr` perhaps in a few steps. It seems that for your task the warp algorithm must read half of the whole input image into memory (129600x64800=8398080000, and 16bit has two bytes per pixel)  plus add some more bytes for its own needs. Using a computer with more memory would be  another option but downsampling the image is cheaper.

Comment: @user30184 thank you for the answer. It is thus a mere problem of memory available net of the size of the input file.

Comment: No, the size of the input file is not a problem as you can see if you use a smaller pixel size. Warping 129600x64800 pixels into 4x2 pixels is not a common use case and it is probably not well tested by GDAL developers. Such sampling is usually tested in steps. For example when https://gdal.org/programs/gdaladdo.html creates several overviews it starts from original data but next overviews are created from the previous ones.